# Send growl message from linux to windows

Tags: linux, windows, growl

Is there any way to send growl message from centos (command line) to windows over network ,

I found this library https://github.com/mattn/gntp-send but I don't know how to use it :(

Answer (score 0):

Register application:
`gntp-send [-a <application>] [-s <host>] <title> <message>`.
`<application>` will be registered and show in Growl settings.

Send message:
`gntp-send 'title' 'message'`

Send message to specific host:
`gntp-send -s windows_host 'title' 'message'`

Answer (score -1):

This is at least much more complicated then it should be, or even impossible.

This seems to be targeting to solve that issue:
https://github.com/obmarg/growlproxy
but didn't work in my case. I have no experience with python - the technology of that solution; and this project seems to be abandoned two years ago.

Anyway I've managed to connect my linux application with growl on my windows - I've just change ip to which i'm connecting and allowed network connections in growlforwindows. If you are using https://github.com/theabraham/growly to send messages, you can change that address in ./lib/gntp.js where it's hardcoded.